# Code shows how many times user click on the button

Tags: closures

I am new to javascript. I try counting the number of clicking times by using closure.

The code is to show how many times the user clicks on the button, but it shows nothing after clicks.

html body code:

```
<button id="clickme">Click me!</button>
<div id="message"></div>
```

js code:

```
  window.onload = function () {
    var button = document.getElementById("clickme");
    button.onclick = handleClick;
  };
  function handleClick() {
    var count = 0;
    var msg = "You clicked me ";
    var div = document.getElementById("message");
    function clicker() {
      count++;
      div.innerHTML = msg + count + " times.";
    }
    return clicker;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make onclick to use the `clicker` function returned by the function `handleClick`, you should invoke the handleClick function.

This type of pattern is also called IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression).

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var button = document.getElementById("clickme");
  button.onclick = handleClick();
};
```

Comment: But isn't it true that reference can also invoke the function?

Comment: Yes, but if you look closely, passing the handleClick to onclick, which means for every click, only handleClick will be invoked, let's simulate the flow of the handleClick function: 1. declare 3 variables, 2. declare a function, 3. return a function, then the whole `handleClick()` is finished, nothing will be executed further.

Comment: And what you want to achieve is that, the declare statement from `handleClick` function, should be executed at the start of the application for preventing duplicated declaration and retrieval, and for every click when `onclick` is triggered, executed the content of `clicker` function. Therefore, `handleClick` function should be executed from the start of the program, which return a `clicker` function, and we pass the `clicker` function to `onclick`, which should behave the way you expected.